# Getting {error,connect_timeout} message while using Hackney

Tags: erlang

i am using [Hackney's](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney) erlang rest client. I followed the steps provided in README.md but I am getting the following error:

```
17> Method = get.
get
18> URL = <<"www.google.com">>.
<<"www.google.com">>
19> Headers = [].
[]
20> Payload = <<>>.
<<>>
21> Options = [].
[]
22>Test  = hackney:request(Method, URL,Headers,Payload,Options).
{error,connect_timeout}
```

I used the same url using curl and wget and both are working. Is there any issue with erlang ssl or issue with tls? I have edited the question for better understanding

EDIT 1 (using curl -vv google.com)

```
curl -vv google.com
* About to connect() to proxy <<ip>> port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying <<ip>>... connected
* Connected to <<ip>> (<<ip>>) port 8080 (#0)
* Proxy auth using Basic with user '<<user>>'
> GET http://google.com HTTP/1.1
> Proxy-Authorization: <<proxy authorization>>
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 03:49:43 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 07 Jul 2016 03:49:43 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 219
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Age: 2223
<
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host <<ip>> left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get when you use the httpc module to do a request via the Erlang shell. 
First start inets:

```
inets:start().
```

Then try:

```
{ok, Response} = httpc:request("https://www.google.com").
```

or

```
{ok, Response} = httpc:request("http://www.google.com").
```

If both of these fail to connect, odds are the issue is not hackney related, but rather an issue of Erlang as a whole.

Comment: I am getting the following message: ** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,{failed_connect,[{to_address,{"www.google.com",443}},{inet,[inet],etimedout}]}}   for both of them

Comment: Then there's an issue with your operating system and Erlang and the issue is most likely not Erlang related.

Comment: I can access the same url using wget and curl...i guess the issue is with erlang

Comment: @SujaySudeep, do you use any proxy? show me `curl -vv google.com`

Comment: @Lol4t0 please check the result of the command provided by you

Comment: @Lol4t0 Thanks it worked...I should have taken care about the proxy..Neway thanks a ton for your help.Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

Hackney do not apply profile proxy settings automatically, so you should take care of proxy settings yourself.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#http-proxy), you should provide the following options:

```
{proxy, {Host, Port}} %% if http proxy is used
{proxy_auth, {User, Password}}. %% if proxy requires authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not an `connect_timeout`. You are getting an exception of `no match of right hand side value` because you are missing the `=` on your last command.
Just change it to

```
{ok, StatusCode, RespHeaders, ClientRef} = hackney:request(Method,URL,Headers,Payload,Options).
```

Comment: Hi Ohad..that was an issue while copying the code in Stackoverflow..Lets make it simple..    Test = hackney:request(Method,URL,Headers,Payload,Options). It give the following error: {error,connect_timeout}